# Test-Path prints false even if the path exists in registry

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-4.0

While debugging a script in VS code's Powershell Integrated Console if I test for a registry path it's printing False even though the path exists.
[image: Failure message]

If I execute the same instruction in PowerShell window or VS Code's Powershell Console it prints True.
[image: Success message]
I am running all instances with Admin privileges.

Comment: Which version of VSCode & PowerShell extension are you using?  Also version of PowerShell itself? (`$PSVersionTable`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with VS code installation. A complete uninstall of VS code and reinstalling it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `Get-PSProvider` shows Registry providers in both Integrated Console and Powershell Console. If it does not exist for some reason, test path simply won't understand Registry:: root. Environments may be different as explained here: https://powershell.org/2013/10/19/the-shell-vs-the-host/

Comment: I checked it. Both provide Registry provider with drives HKLM and HKCU. I have also tried using `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\GMS Software` instead of `Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\GMS Software`. I still get same result.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong <del>syntax</del> argument (I'd suggest testing in the DBG console or the powershell.exe process as an FYI)... Also, don't post code as images, it's a bad practice that will not get your question answered.

The *`PowerShell`* way:

```
Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\GMS Software'
```

Comment: Tried this also but no luck :(

Comment: @Pramod Does your process have access to that path?  Can you use `Get-Item -Path $Path` on that registry key?

Comment: `Get-Item` gives an error even if I execute with admin privileges. The issue is only with VA code's PowerShell Integrated console. In other @TheIncorrigible1 PowerShell consoles like PowerShell, PowerShell ISE or VS Code's Windows PowerShell Console it works fine.

Comment: @Pramod Are you using the latest version?  I've been running into some issues with the PowerShell plugin with some of the past releases of VSCode.  I'd suggest opening an issue on the powershell extension github page if you don't find a working method.

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest version. I will look around and if I don't find a solution I will open an issue. Thanks